# Is it possible to automatically create a new partition in a list partitioned table?

Tags: oracle

The code below would create a new partition if I would insert a date that does not exist in my table. Is it possible to do the same thing in a list partitioned table, where the partition is based on a VARCHAR2 column?

```
 ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY
    PARTITION BY RANGE(DATE) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
( partition MY_PARTITION values less than (to_date('2019-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible starting from the Oracle 12.2.
See the details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-12150FFB-48E4-4169-9EBE-64974C1CEF2A).

Comment: Remember to add a brief detail of your answer apart from the link to the documentation (just in case they move the link some time in the future) :)